# VBA Code to assign names to control buttons instead of letting excel generate button names derived from numbers

Tags: vba, excel

This seems to be a basic question, but I can not figure out how to do this and I cant find the answer on the internet. I have a workbook that I want to generate a series of command buttons for. Each command button is tied to a certain macro. I would really like to have the buttons name themselves according to what they will calculate instead of just generating names such as "button 346". However, I cant figure out how to make this happen. While this is not crucial to my code, it would make the user experience more friendly, and therefore I figure its worth asking if anyone knows what to do.

Here is a sample of my code. I would like to name the button ,"Add Investment"

```
Selection.OnAction = "AB_Investment"
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(2676.75, 90, 131.25, 14.25).Select
```

Please let me know if I can clarify any further. I am still a amateur at vba coding, so I am sorry if this is a super basic question.

Thanks,

Josiah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're worrying about making *"the user experience more friendly"* I guess you are referring to the *text* shown over the button, which calls for its `Caption` property:

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(2676.75, 90, 131.25, 14.25).Select
Selection.Caption = "Add Investments"
```

which can be also shortened down to:

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(2676.75, 90, 131.25, 14.25).Caption = "Add Investments"
```

Comment: would the brave downvoter care to explain the reason why, so to have both me improve my answer and other people learn from his point point of view

Comment: I'm not the down voter but would guess that it was because it's purely a code answer with no explanatory text? Just a guess though.

Answer (score 3):

If you want, you can take it further. As always, it's recommended to stay away from `Select` and `Selection`, but using a referenced object to your created button.

```
Sub AddButton()

Dim Btn As Object

Set Btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(2676.75, 90, 131.25, 14.25)

With Btn
    .Caption = "Add Investments"
    ' you can modify other properties as well
    .Font.Bold = True
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub ButtonNamer()
    ActiveSheet.Buttons.Add(2676.75, 90, 131.25, 14.25).Select
    Selection.Name = "Add Investment"
End Sub
```

[image]

Note:

The **Name** of the button is not the same as its **Caption**.