# How do I name a macro button by means of referencing a cell within the spreadsheet e.g. cell B1 will be the name of the spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, button, naming

I want a macro on the 1st sheet for each subsequent sheet to reflect the name in cell B1
e.g. index page will have 10 macro buttons each button named after the individual sheet name contained in Cell B1

I have no Idea how to automatically reflect the content of a cell as a macro button name other than manually typing in the name into the macro button.

Comment: Maybe this can help [VBA Code to assign names to control buttons instead of letting excel generate button names derived from numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41410003/vba-code-to-assign-names-to-control-buttons-instead-of-letting-excel-generate-bu)